# What is the performance hit (if there is any) when unwrapping swift optional types?

Tags: swift

If I have `var x: CustomType?`, what is the performance hit when using unwrapping `x!`?
Is there meaning of writing following:

```
if let x1 = x {
    f(x1)
    f2(x1)
}
```

or with the same performance I could write:

```
f(x!)
f2(x!)
```

NOTE: I know that in the first case there is checking if the optional is valid, but what if I know that this optional is 100% valid in this code?

Comment: You should  use if let x = x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you are compiling `-Ounchecked` (and *don’t*), they are going to end up very similar, because the runtime is still going to check if the optional contains a value either way (because if you force-unwrap a nil value, you get a runtime assertion, it doesn’t just access the memory as if it weren’t nil).  Something that might give `if let` an edge is that you are telling the compiler more about what you are trying to do, which gives it a better chance of optimizing it.

However, instead of worrying about this, take all the thought effort of wondering which is faster, and more importantly, all the time you spent reasoning about whether it’s safe to use `!` because your variable definitely probably almost certainly isn’t going to be nil (oops except that one time), and put it to better use.

Instead put that time into optimizing the stuff that actually matters.  Look for where you are doing things in `O(n^2)` when you could be doing them in `O(n log n)`.  Think about cache locality.  Think about doing more at compile-time over run-time.  Don’t fuss about something that might be costing you one CPU instruction more than a safer alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the recommendations, I appreciate those, but as a C++ developer with long XP in the area I want to be familiar with all the details, it is just a habit ... and I think it is a good one. There a lot of things you have to consider before optimizing this one - I'm agreeing with you, but I just want to know what is going on under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick benchmark study using the following calculations in Swift 1.2:

```
var x: Int?
x = 0
var startTime: Double = 0

var benchmark1: Double = 0;
var benchmark2: Double = 0;


for var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i {
    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    if let y = x {
        let z = y + y
        println(z)
        benchmark1 += CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    }
}

for var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i {
    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let y = x!
    let z = y + y
    println(z)
    benchmark2 += CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
}

println(benchmark1 / 1000)
println(benchmark2 / 1000)
```

My results consistently are that the `if let y = x` variant takes about 0.00056 seconds, whereas the `let y = x!` variant takes about 0.00059 seconds. So it looks like unwrapping your optionals with `let` is a little bit faster.

I'd be interested to know if this is officially backed up anywhere or if another swift user gets the same results.

Comment: `y` is unused in both benchmarks, so the central part of both benchmarks might be getting optimized out, leaving you with a benchmark that times nothing but the cost of `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` and addition. And 13% variation in wall time might be within margin of error, since there's probably other stuff happening on your machine.

Comment: But really, note the tail part of @AirspeedVelocity's answer: either don't worry about this stuff (at least until you see it making a meaningful difference to *real-world* performance) or make sure you aren't dealing with optionals in a critical section at all. Remember what Knuth said about premature optimization...

Comment: In principal I agree, and wouldn't write code with these differences in mind, but part of the question was also whether or not there was a difference and it seems like that deserves an answer, too. I added an additional calculation to the code and it still yielded the same consistent .00003 difference.

Comment: so, we have ~5% difference

Answer (score 0):

I had the question:

*Is it faster to use (Double), vs. (Double?) ?*

This is more of a worse case scenario than the official question as it's not about let vs force unwrap, it's about using a number type vs an optional number type. I expected a significant difference, however:

**Measured difference: ~5%**

This is similar to the other answer. Swift is very efficient optimizing away optional overhead.